# Struts java-mysql WSO2 deployment error

Tags: java, mysql, struts2

I am trying to deploy a simple struts java-mysql application to WSO2 cloud.

In my local the appllication runs perfectly, but when I open the cloud link I am getting the below error:

```
access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "template/xhtml/theme.properties" "read") - Class: java.security.AccessControlContext
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not too familiar with WSO2 cloud but the error is clear that theme.properties file is not accessible while deployment, do check the permissions to the file system properly. 

Check if the your application folder is accessible to the container you are deploying your app on.
eg. Your web app may be owned by user1 and the container may be started by user2. 

 Please be sure about that.

Comment: Thank u @Prakash Joshi for replying. But the thing is I am not able to find theme.properties file.                                                                                                                                 I evn chnged in catalina policy of tomcat                                                                   permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.util.logging.config.class", "read"; To   permission java.security.AllPermission;